# Different print preview

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to display print preview before printing.

```
rngprint.PrintOut Preview:=True
```

However, the print preview displayed is different from what I would get by selecting File/Print.

How do I get File/Print style print preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following instead

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PrintPreviewAndPrint"
```

It simulates a click on the ribbon button.

Comment: Sometimes, the print preview would display just a blank page. I don't know how to solve that problem except closing and re-opening Excel.

Comment: @joehua please open a new question if you want to ask something else and provide more information.

Comment: It's the same question. The code you gave opened the preview window but sometimes, I only saw a blank page. I tries "Print Active Sheet", "Print Selection", etc. to no avail. I don't know why it works some times but not the other times. When it didn't work, I had to close Excel and re-open it to get the preview to work right.

Comment: No, actually your original question was *"How do I get File/Print style print preview?"* and it was already answered. So this issue is new and not the original question. The issue with asking in comments is you cannot show the code properly that you used and we cannot answer it properly. • This command does exactly the same as clicking on the button in the ribbon (nothing more). If you do something else like `Print Active Sheet` that cannot work. You need to be on the correct sheet and then run the command. If you then get an issue still please ask a new question and include your code there.